# I have a problem when trying to run my react native app

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

as referenced in the react native docs, I am trying to run my react native app with the command npx react-native run-ios on terminal. However, I am getting this error:
[image]

How do I fix it? I already tried deleting the build file in Xcode.

Comment: Try to run ```pod install``` command inside ios directory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have executed the react-native link command. From react-native 0.60.0, there is no need of linking the native dependencies manually. Unlink the node modules that are causing the respective errors as suggested by Joshua Obritsch and run pod install again.

Answer (score 0):

You have manually linked libraries by doing react-native link but react-native 0.60 onwards linking is automatic. SO first do ,

```
react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler
react-native unlink react-native-reanimated
react-native unlink react-native-screens
```

Then after that try `pod install` and it should be fine.